# Need to assign the x-axis values consistent with the calculations used

Tags: plotting

I'm capitalizing on someone else's work with regard to steam tables.  I wanted to make some unusual kind of charts.  I can get most of the way to the chart design.  But I have trouble with the x-axis, which I'd like it to be the temperature in the calculations (tvalue)

```
tvalue = {5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350,400}

pcurve1 =Table[ThermodynamicData["Water","Enthalpy", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[tvalue,"DegreesCelsius"],"Pressure" -> Quantity[i, "Bar"]}], {i, {500, 50, 40, 30, 20,10,5, 2, 1}}];

ListLinePlot[pcurve1,PlotLabels -> {500, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

This produces a chart close to what I want.  Except that the x-axis is the sequence from 1 to 14, from the tvalue list.  But what I want the x-axis to be is the actual temperatures used to determine the enthalpy (5, 10, 20, etc.).  DataRange will insert a range of values, but not consistent with tvalue.

I tried the folks at Wolfram and they told me just to transpose tvalue, and pcurve1.  Doesn't work though.

Your thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct lists of `{x, y}` pairs from `pcurve1` and `tvalue` using (1) [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) (or [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)), or, alternatively, (2) [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) and specify the horizontal ticks using the option [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html):

```
ListLinePlot[Thread[{tvalue, #}] & /@ pcurve1,
 PlotLabels -> {500, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1}, 
 Ticks -> {Delete[tvalue, List /@ {2, 4, 5}], Automatic},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[TemporalData[pcurve1, {tvalue}],
 PlotLabels -> {500, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1}, 
 Ticks -> {Delete[tvalue, List /@ {2, 4, 5}], Automatic},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Note:** I deleted several elements from `tvalue` to specify horizontal ticks to avoid label overlaps.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: I think I followed everything until   Ticks -> {Delete[tvalue, List /@ {2, 4, 5}].  What exactly is the Delete... doing?